# How do I run this loop with just apply in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, called try_out, that has columns raw_street, raw_number, raw_postalCode and raw_locality and around 1000 rows

And I wrote a function, google_clean, that takes street, number, postal code and locality as arguments.

This loop would work to clean all the addresses:

```
for(i in 1:length(try_out)){
  google_clean(try_out[i, "raw_street"],
             try_out[i, "raw_number"],
             try_out[i, "raw_postalCode"],
             try_out[i, "raw_locality"])
}
```

Can somebody however advice me how I would better write this with the apply function in R?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: What do you mean? Should I post the whole function google clean that I have created?

Comment: Why would want to do this with `apply`? It won't speed things up (if this is what you hope for), and the syntax is pretty much the same in this case

Comment: It is easier to understand the question if you have a sample dataset on which the function needs to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the `google_clean` function so that instead of taking those 4 arguments, it takes a vector of length 4. Then a line like this should work to iterate over the rows of `try_out`:

```
new_object = apply(try_out,1,google_clean)
```

You would probably need to transpose `new_object` since the number of rows in `try_out` would be equal to the number of columns in `new_object`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
mapply(google_clean, 
       try_out[,"raw_street"], 
       try_out[,"raw_number"], 
       try_out[,"raw_postalCode"], 
       try_out[,"raw_locality"])
```

Answer (score 1):

(you mention 1:length(try_out) in your question, but maybe you mean nrow(try_out)?) Use `Map` to apply a function to several arguments; save a little typing by using `with`

```
with(try_out, {
    Map(google_clean, raw_street, raw_number, raw_postalCode, raw_Locality)
})
```

Its worth using Map (and other apply functions) because it manages the creation of the result list for you, and because it suggests opportunities for vectorization. In particular your google_clean function should probably work on *vectors* of raw_street, etc, instead of scalars so you'd write

```
with(try_out, google_clean(raw_street, raw_number, raw_postalCode, raw_Locality))
```